SNAP ERROR: "ESD Measurement" is not legal for JDOM/XML elements: XML name 'ESD Measurement' cannot contain the character " "
Firstly, I apologize for my English, I am not very fluent.
I have a problem when I try to write a Sentinel 1 product in a POLSARPRO format. As seen in the picture, the error is

The name "ESD Measurement" is not legal for JDOM/XML elements: XML name 'ESD Measurement' cannot contain the character " ".


If someone knows why this error appears or another method to make the conversion, please let me know.

I found the problem. Right-click on the .dim file, search for "ESD Measurement", and remove the space.
